# How do i create a posix non real time task?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I want to create two posix thread. One of them should be a Real time task with some specified priority and the other one should be a "posix non-rt task.

To create the posix-rt-task with priority I use

```
#include <pthread.h>


#include <sched.h>

pthread_attr_t tattr;

pthread_t tid;

int ret;

int newprio = 20;

sched_param param;

ret = pthread_attr_init (&tattr);

ret = pthread_attr_getschedparam (&tattr, &param);

param.sched_priority = newprio;

ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam (&tattr, &param);

ret = pthread_create (&tid, &tattr, func, arg);
```

However, who do I specifiy  a posix task with no priority? I.O.W a non RT task!?
I've read on the internet and found something about shed_other. In case it is the supposed one to use, how do I type it? What is the code flow?
Thanks in advance!

*Interaction between posix RT-task and another posix non-RT-task*

---

Comment: Isn't "non-rt" the *default* when creating threads? I.e. just call `pthread_create` without any attributes (pass `NULL` as the attribute pointer).

Comment: maybe, i'm not really sure. However, I would like to specifiy that the task is non-real time task. sched_other properly is the keyword, still, i'm not really sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer that my question was rhetorical. If you don't want any specific scheduling policy or priority, then don't use any attributes.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification. But what is the differense then between creating a posix thread without attributes, and creating a posix thread using sched_other?

Comment: From [the **Linux** scheduling manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html): "`SCHED_OTHER` is the standard Linux time-sharing scheduler that is intended for all threads that do not require the special real-time mechanisms." As long as you don't change priority or policy, your threads will be using `SCHED_OTHER` with its only allowed priority of `0`. Other systems might have other defaults.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the clarification! I will for sure check the Linux manual.